# How to handle environment variable 'type' in Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have a powershell script in which I need to get 'the next number'. I save the current value in an environment variable. Example:

```
$perfRunIndex = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PPRunIndex","User")
$perfRunIndex = $perfRunIndex + 1
[environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PPRunIndex","$perfRunIndex","User")

$jobName = "PerfCounter-$perfRunIndex"
Write-Host "`njobname = $jobName ..."
```

I ran this script a few times yesterday from Powershell ISE, and I got 0, 1, 2, 3 displayed on successive runs of the script. This morning I opened Powershell ISE and opened and ran the script, and I got 31, 311, 3111, etc. What caused the environment variable 'type' to change to 'string'? How can I ensure it is always treated as a 'number'?

Comment: Define the variable as Interger or double? [INT]$Variable, [Double]$Variable

Comment: `$perfRunIndex = [int]$perfRunIndex + 1` or `$perfRunIndex = 1 + $perfRunIndex`

Comment: Environment variable values are strings. If you want PowerShell to treat an environment variable's value as a number, you have to tell it to do so.

Comment: Why are you using environment variables to store perfcounter job information anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by making $perfRunIndex be of type [Int]

```
[Int]$perfRunIndex = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PPRunIndex","User")
```

(Thanks to @Bill_Stewart, @BenH and @guiwhatsthat for this answer to my question.)

Comment: The comments to my original question were the real answer, but I could find no way to mark a comment as an answer. Also there was no way to up-vote those responses, but I think there should be. This 'answer' is only to give credit where it is due.